# Can't `relevel` a factor variable in data frame because it is an `integer`, how to fix?

Tags: r

I have a `tibble` data frame in R called `research_fields`:

```
# A tibble: 411 × 2
   Response_ID Field              
         <int> <fct>              
 1           1 Business           
 2           2 Psychology         
 3           3 Medicine and health
 4           4 Other              
 5           5 Medicine and health
 6           6 Education          
 7           7 Public policy      
 8           8 Computer science   
 9           9 Biology            
10          10 Medicine and health
# … with 401 more rows
```

The `Field` variable is already a factor, but I want to use `forcats::fct_relevel()` to move the "Other" factor to be the last, so I tried this:

```
fct_relevel(research_fields$"Field", "Other", Inf)
```

But I get the error:

```
Error:
! Can't convert a number to a character vector.
```

I don't understand why because `Field` is clearly a factor (`fct`), not an integer. Why is this?

**How to I make "Other" come last? Is there a way to do this with `mutate()` and something else from `forcats::` perhaps?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to name the `after=` parmeter when calling `fct_relevel`

```
fct_relevel(research_fields$Field, "Other", after=Inf)
```

This is because the function signature is

```
fct_relevel(.f, ..., after = 0L)
```

That means that if you don't use `after=` then all the values you passed get sucked in to the `...` and are assumed to be level names and the numeric value for infinity is clearly not a valid level name.

Comment: I see! The explanation is really helpful, I see why the `after=` is important and meaningful. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might need a better conception of what a `"factor"` variable is. Let's assume we have this factor variable with the associated levels.

```
head(df$Field)
# [1] Jan May Jan Sep Oct Apr
# 12 Levels: Apr Aug Dec Feb Jan Jul Jun Mar May Nov ... Sep
```

An easy thing to do is to create a `factor` again with arbitrary `levels=` in the desired order (in this example we want of course the right order of the months).

```
df$Field <- factor(df$Field, levels=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", 
                                      "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))
```

The variable stays the same, but the levels have changed.

```
head(df$Field)
# [1] Jan May Jan Sep Oct Apr
# 12 Levels: Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct ... Dec
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(Field=factor(month.abb[sample(1:12, 50, replace=TRUE)]))
```